# Como obtengo un numero con 1 decimal sin redondear en javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con los decimales, ya que estoy obteniendo un numero por ejemplo 
2.7607 y estoy sacando 1 decimal con la funcion toFixed(1) pero me devuelve 2.8 ya que lo redondea pero necesito que quede el 2.7 solamente.

Alguien que me pueda colabora porfavor.

Gracias!!

Comment: Se acaba de responder una pregunta identica hace un par de semanas, pero no puedo encontrarla. Cuando la encuentre la pongo por aca.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes convertir el número en un string y luego obtener el número solamente hasta la primer posición decimal:

```
num.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,1})?/)[0];
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Esta función recorta `n` decimal sin redondear y sin regex:

```js
function cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(numFloat, toFixed) {

    let isNegative = false;

    // Comprobamos si el valor es negativo
    if ( numFloat < 0 ) {
        numFloat *= -1; // Equivale a Math.abs();     
        isNegative = true;
    }

    // Recogemos el valor ANTES del separador
    let numFloat_bf = numFloat.toString().split('.')[0];

    // Recogemos el valor DESPUÉS del separador
    let numFloat_af = numFloat.toString().split('.')[1];

    // Recortar los decimales según el valor de 'toFixed'
    if (numFloat_af) {
        numFloat_af = `.${numFloat_af.slice(0, -numFloat_af.length + toFixed)}`; 
    }
    
    // Retornamos el valor en float y añadimos el signo '-' si es negativo
    return parseFloat(`${( isNegative ? '-': '' )}${numFloat_bf}${numFloat_af}`);
}

const num1 = 1.1744825; // 1.1
const num2 = -45.29465; // -45.2
const num3 = '-122.37'; // -122.3
const num4 = '84.4607'; // 84.4
const num5 = 5;         // 5
const num6 = -9.600812; // -9.6
const num7 = 7.030201;  // 7

console.log( cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(num1, 1) );
console.log( cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(num2, 1) );
console.log( cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(num3, 1) );
console.log( cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(num4, 1) );
console.log( cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(num5, 1) );
console.log( cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(num6, 1) );
console.log( cutDecimalsWithoutRounding(num7, 1) );
```

Comment: Esta bien amigo, pero si le pasas solo un entero falla

Comment: @JGuerreroS - Gracias por avisar... arreglado!

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener solo 1 decimal sin redondear, puede hacer lo siguiente:

- Primero multiplicamos el número por `10`, así movemos el punto decimal un lugar a la derecha
- Luego, obtenemos la parte entera del nuevo número (`eg: parseInt`).
- Por ultimo lo dividimos de nuevo por `10`, para así obtener `1` solo decimal.

### Demo:

```js
var num = 2.7607;
console.log(parseInt(num * 10, 10) / 10);
```

### Opcional:

Si quisieras `n` decimales sin redondear, entonces podrías hacerlo así:

```js
function myRound(num, dec) {
  var exp = Math.pow(10, dec || 2); // 2 decimales por defecto
  return parseInt(num * exp, 10) / exp;
}

var num = 2.7617;
console.log('Con 1 decimales:', myRound(num, 1));
console.log('Con 2 decimales:', myRound(num));
console.log('Con 3 decimales:', myRound(num, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución con [**`Math.floor()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
function getOneDecimal(num) {
  return Math.floor(num * 10) / 10;
}

console.log(getOneDecimal(2.7607));
```

O también, convirtiendo a `string` y extrayendo el caracter después del `.` con [**`indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```js
function getOneDecimal(num) {
  let string = num.toString();
  return Number(string.substring(0, string.indexOf('.') + 2));
}

console.log(getOneDecimal(2.7607));
```